# Sending a file via http in Python with bottle framework

Tags: python, http, download, wsgi, bottle

How can I send a file as answer to an HTTP request in Python using the bottle framework?

For upload this code works for me:

```
@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    category   = request.forms.get('category')
    upload     = request.files.get('upload')
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.raw_filename)
    if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'):
        return 'File extension not allowed.'

    save_path = category
    upload.raw_filename = "hoho" + ext
    upload.save(save_path) # appends upload.filename automatically
    return 'OK'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call [Bottle's `static_file` function](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files) and return its result:

```
@route('/static/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/static/files')
```

That example, when called with url `/static/myfile.txt`, will return the contents file `/path/to/static/files/myfile.txt`.

Other SO questions (like [this one](http://from%20bottle%20import%20static_file%20@route('/images/%3Cfilename:re:.*%5C.png%3E')%20def%20send_image(filename):%20%20%20%20%20return%20static_file(filename,%20root='/path/to/image/files',%20mimetype='image/png')%20%20@route('/static/%3Cfilename:path%3E')%20def%20send_static(filename):%20%20%20%20%20return%20static_file(filename,%20root='/path/to/static/files'))) contain additional examples.

Comment: I wonder if it's okay to serve static files with `bottle`, or better put `nginx` in front of it?